# Text in input button not showing up

Tags: html, css

I really wouldn't ask such a silly question if I wasn't stumped. My submit button isn't showing any text. I'm not hiding the text or setting something like line-height: 0 anywhere in my CSS. I've been at this for hours, it's become really frustrating for me:

Here's the page in question:

http://rex.gear.host/Admin/AddProduct.aspx

The button at the bottom is the submit button.

Comment: You should post code instead of a link to a site since most people wont follow unknown links.

Comment: @DanielB I agree with you. Some can be shown only on the particular place where it works. Right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a `font-size: 0px` that doesn't allow you to display the text.

There is this rule:

```
form {font-size: 0px;}
input, button {font-size: inherit;}
button {font-size: 1.5em;}
```

Anything multiplied by `0` is `0`. So this rule gets cascaded and you have got something like this.

Comment: That was quick...adding line..font-size:18px; will solve..upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Leothelion I explained the reason behind too!

Comment: I was almost absolutely sure that the button rule will override it properly. Totally forgot that em is a multiplicative of the current font size (which was 0)... I feel like a complete idiot now. Thanks :D

Comment: I was just waiting for 10mins to pass. Couldn't accept it before that.

Answer (score 0):

`.submitbtn {font-size: 1.5em;}` (in `ProductForm.css` at `line 120`) multiplies the inherit fontsize that you have, with just changing it to `.submitbtn {font-size: 15px;}` your problem should be solved.

A part from that, inn `ProductForm.css` at `line 3` you've got:

```
form {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 30px 60px 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

This `font-size: 0;` makes your text invisible because `1.5em` with the `inherit` text size of 0, results in font-size = 0 (like  also said  Praveen Kumar in his answer).

Just edit it and problem resolved :)

Comment: What you said is wrong man. `em` works in all the browsers. Check my answer for the right reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
style="font-size: 20px;"
```

If I change this in my chrome browser, then the text appear.

You can add it with inline css or in the submitbtn class

Comment: please be clear with your answer..where to add this css?

Comment: Well..there is no race..come with proper solution by which other user can get clear view to solve the issue..hope you will understand..ty

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add:

```
.col-submit .submitbtn {font-size: 14px;}
```

It seems like `.submitbtn {font-size: 1.5em;}` is not working.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I was't saying that em is not working at all :D. I just said that **it seems** not working (for this case).

Comment: Okay sorry then. My mistake in understanding your answer!